# How do I detect long blocking functions in Tornado application

Tags: python, profiling, tornado

I have a Tornado application and sometimes somebody adds a code that blocks for an inappropriate time.

How do I detect such functions, maybe even log which handler/coroutine method blocks for a time longer than, say, 50ms?

I'm looking at `_make_coroutine_wrapper()` in `tornado.gen`, and don't see a way to cut in, except for modifying the source - which is ok for a one-time debugging, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold) method. `set_blocking_log_threshold(0.050)` will print a stack trace any time the IOLoop is blocked for longer than 50ms.

Comment: It seems this is no longer supported in Tornado. Has anyone found a replacement?

Comment: As documented in the [Tornado 5.1 docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch5.1/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold), the replacement for this method is the environment variable `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1`, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode)